# How to hide a div class in my page using css code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am developing a site of my own using WordPress and I am stuck at a situation. I would like to remove the white bar below the header image so my main page's content gets displayed higher. This white bar is useless as I cannot edit or move it. I would really appreciate it if any of you could create a custom CSS code for me that'll solve my issue. Thanks a lot in advance.

Here's the website: [www.okosmostismousikis.net](http://www.okosmostismousikis.net/)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GntxG.jpg

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Excuse me if my type of writing is inappropriate. The truth is that I didn't have the time to read the guide you linked. I'll go through it to become better for the next time. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to inspect in the firebug, and find the problem. If unable to that simply do the following changes
add in the css

```
.mythemes-white.mythemes-default-content{
    display:none;
 }
```